# Populate xml data into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datatable

I'm trying to read data from xml file and populate into SQL server table. My xml file structure is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Methods>
  <Method>
    <ColName>ColName1</ColName>
    <ColID>ColID1</ColID>
    <Col1>Column1Row1</Col1>
    <Col2>Column2Row1</Col2>
    <Col3>Column3Row1</Col3>
    <Col4>Column3Row1</Col4>
  </Method>
  <Method>
    <ColName>ColName2</ColName>
    <ColID>ColID2</ColID>
    <Col1>Column1Row2</Col1>
    <Col4>Column3Row2</Col4>
  </Method>
  </Methods>
```

The whole xml file is created using XSLT except the Col4 that is added to the xml file later in C# using:

```
XElement Col4 = new XElement("Col4", "Value");
```

When I use the following code:

```
xmlFileReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlfilepath, new XmlReaderSettings());
dataset.ReadXml(xmlFileReader);
```

The data is getting populated into multiple datatables. In the second datatable the Col4 information is stored with column name Col4_Text.

When I use the following code:

```
string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(xmlfile);
dataset.ReadXml(XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root.Element("Method").CreateReader());
```

The above xml nodes are present under Method node. The parent node of Method is Methods.

I'm getting all the columns data in one datatable. But, it returns only first row information. The reason i'm populating the xml data into dataset is to loop through the dataset and populate the data into SQL Server table.

Please let me know how to get all the data into one datatable or how to populate multiple datatables data into SQL Servertable or let me know the best way to populate xml data from above scenario such that I can log the details of records that failed to populate in SQL Server table.